# Open an activity in a touch way android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-touch-event

In my first activity touching left or right opens the second activity
Of the value calculation X and Y The activity is opened based on the conditions. This is part of the code

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    if (v.getId() == R.id.layout3) {

        float currentX = event.getX();
        float currentY = event.getY();

        if ((currentX > 160.0) && (currentY > 5.0) && (currentY < 55.0) &&(downXValue < 146.0)){       
            startActivity(i); 
        }
    }
    break;
```

So here everything goes well.
The problem is that the activity opens repeatedly accumulating above each other
If I want to go back to the first activity, you should press the button more than five times
This means that the second activity opened more than five times.
I am new at Android. I want to know where the problem is and what are the correct methods and where are the mistakes. Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing youre using touch listeners. Since yours (and everyones) finger is to big, almost every tap is counted as multiple screen touches. So, add a flag that after criterium is fulfiled startActivity is no longer called.

Comment: Thank you for useful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a flag to check if the activity is already started:

```
private activityStarted = false;

if (!activityStarted && (currentX > 160.0) && (currentY > 5.0) && (currentY < 55.0) && (downXValue < 146.0)){   
    activityStarted = true;    
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where will I make her come back false

Comment: You can do it in onResume

Comment: Thank you ,I made them return false in onResume They became good